# Google Script error , wont run and pull through

Tags: e

```
}catch(e){
  var msg = "Run failed with error: " + e;
  Logger.log(msg)
```

Tried re- running and it wasnt a bug , seems to happen every few weeks, and will pull through part of the data but not all of it. Can anyone point me in a direction to start